# IDEA doesn't offer to replace a null check + dot action to `?.`

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I have the following code example below.

Replacing the following null check + dot action

```
a != null && a.toInt() == b
```

with `?.`

```
a?.toInt() == b
```

"seems" to do the same job and even clearer.

But, as you can see in the image, IDEA doesn't suggest the replacement.

Perhaps the two expressions aren't equivalent?

Example code:

```
fun main() {
    val a: String? = initA()
    val b = 1
    if (a != null && a.toInt() == b) {
        println("true")
    } else {
        println("false")
    }
}
```

Screencap:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second I clicked post I understood.

If  `b`'s type is changes to nullable, meaning:

```
val b: Int?
```

Those expressions cease to be equivalent.

If both `a` and `b` are null, the behavior will be different.

Comment: Yes, it could be the case the inspection isn't currently sophisticated enough to check if `b` is non-nullable.